# multiple questions about setting up survey weights with the application of a combination of different types of weights - ESS

Tags: survey, survey-sampling, survey-weights, cluster-sample

Checking out this file published by *the european social survey website*

https://www.europeansocialsurvey.org/docs/methodology/ESS_weighting_data_1.pdf

it states that :

• when analysing data for one country alone, only the design weight or the poststratification weight need to be applied.

• when comparing data from two or more countries but without reference to statistics
that combine data from more than one country, only the design weight or the poststratification weight need be applied.

• when comparing data of two or more countries and with reference to the average (or
combined total) of those countries, design or post-stratification weight in combination with population size weights should be applied.

• when combining different countries to describe a group of countries or a region, such
as "accession countries" or "EU member states", design or post-stratification weights
in combination with population size weights should be applied.

1- Are these rules applicable for all kinds of surveys from all around the world? or only for european countries ?

2- As we can only use either design weights or post-stratification weights in combination with population size weights, how do we choose between the first two types of weighting methods ?

3 - The last question : The formula for population size weight defined by this file is :
PWEIGHT=[Population size aged 15 years and above]/[(Net sample size in country)*10 000].

In the case where the target population is made of children aged less than 15 years old, how shall we set up the population size weights ?

Thanks.